# Material UI Tooltip - Customize flip behavior

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Could you please help, how to better customize Tooltip flip behavior
https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-https-v3ejo?file=/src/App.js

Comment: What do you mean by "flip behavior"?

Comment: What do you mean by "better"?

Comment: Often for popper.js you can customize flip behavior: if there are not enough space from bottom/top it will render popup dialog on the right side for example

Comment: "better" mean that doesn't work for me now

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.